# Feathersjs setting up issue

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I am new to featherjs when I run npm install and run by using npm start I am getting the below error. I tried to use the one sample project from github [https://github.com/swina/feathersjs-webpush-notifications][1]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you need a `secret` (and probably additional) configuration for authentication. This is usually located in `config/default.json` (or `config/<environment>.json`). Have a look at the [feathers-chat configuration](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/crow/config/default.json) which is the standard configuration generated by the CLI and the recommended way to get started. More information on authentication configuration can be found in the [authentication API documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/service.html#configuration).

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me. I replaced the feathers default.json with on from feathers chat configuration and replaced private and public keys.